# Apache showing empty "index of /", after dist upgrade

Tags: apache, apache2.4, apache2.2, debian-jessie

I'm working on a Debian 7 server which I did a dist upgrade on so it is Debian 8 now.

The only thing I am having trouble with is the apache2 which got updated from 2.2 to 2.4. the problem that is that now it shows me an empty "Index of /" although there are a lot of files in the specified folders.

vHost Conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin some@email
  ServerName some.server
  ServerAlias some.server
  DocumentRoot "/data/apt/public_html"

  <Directory "/data/apt/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

How can I get it working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mixing 2.2 and 2.4 access directives is not recommended.  Look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html.  You will see that they never mix `Order allow,deny` with `Require all granted`.  So remove your `Order` line.

> Mixing old and new directives
>
> Mixing old directives like Order, Allow or Deny with new ones like
>   Require is technically possible but discouraged. mod_access_compat was
>   created to support configurations containing only old directives to
>   facilitate the 2.4 upgrade. Please check the examples below to get a
>   better idea about issues that might arise.

Also, you do not specify a `DocumentIndex` file so Apache does not know which file it should return a client when he asks for `http://some.server/`.

Let's assume the default page is index.html, add this in your VirtualHost:

```
DocumentIndex index.html
```

Note 1: `ServerAlias` has the same value as `ServerName`, and is therefore not required.
Note 2: you should setup access and error log files for this VirtualHost.  It might not be useful if you have only 1 VirtualHost, but you will thank me if you have a large site (with multiple VH later).

Comment: Hey Nic,

thanks for your answer. it is an apt repository so there is no Main Page. But it helped that you pointed out that Require and Order schoudn't be used together.
i got it to work in the end.